Pandas Value to a column based on multiple conditions from another columns
I have following Dataframe in pandas & have to derive a col "E" based on condition.
rankings = {'Vol A % ': [266.2, 266.6, 258.81, 232.84],
            'Vol B %': [233.8, 233.4, 241.19, 267.16],
            'Effo A % ': [235.61, 251.48 , 264.99, 232.59 ],
            'Effo B % ': [264.39, 248.52, 235.01,267.41]}
df = pd.DataFrame(rankings)

I have added 2 more columns "Vol" & "Eff".
"Vol" col is based on if the "Vol A %" is greater than "Vol B %", then value of "Vol" col is A & value should be B if vice versa.
In the same way "Eff" col is based on if the "Effo A %" is greater than "Effo B %", then value of "Eff" col is A & B if vice versa. I am using following code for the same.
df.loc[df['Vol pos %'] > df['Vol neg %'], 'Vol'] = 'Pos'
df.loc[df['Vol pos %'] < df['Vol neg %'], 'Vol'] = 'Neg'

df.loc[df['Effo pos %'] > df['Effo neg %'], 'Eff'] = 'Pos'
df.loc[df['Effo pos %'] < df['Effo neg %'], 'Eff'] = 'Neg'

Now, I want to have a col "E" which is to be derived as if max of "Vol A%" & "Vol B %" is greater then Max of "Effo A%" & "Effo B%" the E should be ("Value of "Vol" col) more than  (Value of Eff Col) Effo".
The final table should look like below.
Vol A % Vol B % Effo A %    Effo B %    Vol Eff               E
266.2   233.8   235.61       264.39      A   B   A vol more than B Effo
266.6   233.4   251.48       248.52      A   A   A vol more than A Effo
258.81  241.19  264.99       235.01      A   A   Pos Effo more than Pos vol
232.84  267.16  232.59       267.41      B   B   Neg Effo more than Neg vol


Have you read this Q/A? You should be able to use np.select

Or Pandas case_when
